# How to configure subdomains in bitnami ruby stack

Tags: node.js, apache, virtualhost, bitnami

I am using Bitnami ruby stack on Google Cloud which supports php and nodejs at the same time. I have want my express js app which I want to run on main domain. eg `www.example.com` and I have two other codeigniter app (PHP) which I want them to run on subdomains like `one.example.com` and the other on domain like `two.example.com`.

I have followed different Bitnami articles such these [1](https://docs.bitnami.com/general/infrastructure/lapp/configuration/configure-custom-application/) [2](https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/infrastructure/lamp/administration/create-custom-application-php/) [3](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/nodejs/administration/create-custom-application-nodejs/) but still I can't have both apps run well together.

I placed all apps inside `/opt/bitnami/apps` and every app folder has 2 sub folders which are conf and htdocs just as described in article.

Here are contents of **conf** folder of codeigniter app which I want it to run on **subdomain**.

**/opt/bitnami/apps/one/conf/httpd-app.conf**

```
<Directory /opt/bitnami/apps/one/htdocs/>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
</Directory>
```

**/opt/bitnami/apps/one/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName one.example.com
    ServerAlias www.one.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/one/htdocs"
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [R=permanent,L]

    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/one/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8444>
    ServerName one.example.com
    ServerAlias www.one.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/one/htdocs"
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [R=permanent,L]

    Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/one/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

And **conf** of nodejs app which I want to run on main domain.

**/opt/bitnami/apps/main/conf/httpd-app.conf**

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:2000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:2000/
```

**/opt/bitnami/apps/nyererefy/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  # redirect www and non-www http routes to https-non-www:
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

  Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/main/conf/httpd-app.conf"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  #redirect https-wwww to https-non-www
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

  Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/main/conf/httpd-app.conf"
 </VirtualHost>
```

**/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf**

```
# Bitnami applications installed in a prefix URL
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/phpmyadmin/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/phppgadmin/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/letsencrypt/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
```

**/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf**

```
# Bitnami applications installed in a Virtual Host
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/one/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf"
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/main/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf"
```

**/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf**

```
# Default Virtual Host configuration.

<IfVersion < 2.3 >
  NameVirtualHost *:80
  NameVirtualHost *:443
</IfVersion>

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

  # Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>

# Default SSL Virtual Host configuration.

<IfModule !ssl_module>
  LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
</IfModule>

Listen 443
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !EDH !RC4"
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
  SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key"

  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.3 >
      Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

  # Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
</VirtualHost>

# Bitnami applications that uses virtual host configuration
Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf"

# Status
ExtendedStatus on
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
ServerName local-stackdriver-agent.stackdriver.com
<Location /server-status>
  SetHandler server-status
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

How to configure them to run together?

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here!

You need to configure all your applications to use Apache virtual hosts.

First, you need to change the default root application to be configured with virtual host instead of using the Apache prefix.

This is done through the files `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf` and `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf`.

Second, you need to configure your codeigniter applications as virtual hosts too. This guide may be helpful.

https://docs.bitnami.com/general/infrastructure/lapp/configuration/configure-custom-application/

Also, if you have any issues feel free to open a case in the Bitnami community forum.

Comment: Some tips. First of all, I see that in the `/opt/bitnami/apps/one/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf` file, you use the ports 8080 and 8443 when Apache is using 80 and 443. You will need to change that. Apart from following the guide Tomas shared, you can also take a look at [this one](https://docs.bitnami.com/general/infrastructure/ruby/administration/redirect-custom-domains/) where we explain how to create a virtual host. Please let us know if you get any error when restating Apache